# How to omit the dot after the year and add comma after the author on \parencite

Tags: biblatex

When I `\parencite` something I want the dot to be omitted after the year and to add a comma after the author.
The following commands are already in my preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space} % add colon after year on \parencite
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1} %no page prefix when citing
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1} %no page prefix when citing
```

This displays my cited source as

> (Author 1975.: 49)

but  I want them to be shown as

> (Author, 1975: 49)

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[serbian]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \parencite[42]{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mhh, there shouldn't be a period/dot in the first place. It isn't there by default and the code shown so far in the question does not add it. Please show us a fully compilable example document (with `.bib` entry) that reproduces what you are seeing. At the moment **I cannot reproduce the undesirable output**, https://gist.github.com/moewew/d29d6091cc2fbfe02a167c4c2c9da5cc looks just fine.

Comment: There may be something different because I use Serbian babel. Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/Fooftilly/caf9a286315ed9101e51e4657b0b6da2

Comment: The dot in Serbian was explicitly put in by the localisation contributor. If a dot is unacceptable or unusual for year-only dates, please open an issue at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues, so this can be discussed.

Comment: It's come down to individual preference. Some authors and journals like (Author, 2020, 54), some do (Author 2020: 54) and some (Author 2020.: 54). There's no standard way to do it in Serbian journals (or other Balkan journals) and the authors do it according to the journal rules. It's some sort of broken APA-like system where every journal sets some weird rules on the top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`serbian.lbx` puts `\adddot` after the year in `\mkbibdateshort` and relates macros. You can get rid of the dots by redefining the macros within `\DefineBibliographyExtras{serbian}`.

You can add a comma after the author with `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}`.

```
\documentclass[serbian]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[serbian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{serbian}{%
  \renewcommand*\mkbibordinal[1]{\stripzeros{#1}}
  \renewcommand*\mkbibdateshort[3]{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}{}{\mkbibordinal{\thefield{#3}}%
      \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\addnbspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\mkbibordinal{\thefield{#2}}%
      \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\addnbspace}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}%
    {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \renewcommand*\mkbibseasondateshort[2]{%
    \mkbibseason{\thefield{#2}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}%
    \dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}%
    \renewcommand*\mkbibseasondatelong[2]{%
    \mkbibseason{\thefield{#2}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}%
    \dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}%
}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space} % add colon after year on \parencite
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1} %no page prefix when citing
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1} %no page prefix when citing


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \parencite[380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \parencite[42]{elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This seems to produce the desired output, but may have side effects and break things in other places.

[image]